# RabbitMQ - Socket Closed Exception - Windows Server 2012

Tags: python, sockets, rabbitmq, windows-server-2012, python-pika

So I have a publisher which is using **schedule** python package to read data from a file and every 5-10 mins and publish each line to a queue.
On the other side I have consumer using something like:

```
self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
self.channel = self.connection.channel()
while True:
        method, properties, body = self.channel.basic_get(queue=conf.UNIVERSAL_MESSAGE_QUEUE, no_ack=False)
        if body is not None:
            self.assign_task(body=body)
            self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

        else:
            self.logger.info('channel empty')
            self.move_to_done()
            time.sleep(5)
```

Assign task function looks like:

```
def assign_task(body=body):
       <do something with the message body>
```

For some reason after a while it throws the following error:

```
2017-08-03 15:27:43,756: ERROR: base_connection.py: _handle_error:   335: Socket Error: 10054
2017-08-03 15:27:43,756: WARNING: base_connection.py: _check_state_on_disconnect:   180: Socket closed when connection was open
2017-08-03 15:27:43,756: WARNING: connection.py: _on_disconnect:   1360: Disconnected from RabbitMQ at localhost:5672 (0): Not specified
```

Essentially both publisher and consumer are 2 different python programs intended to run on a single machine with Windows Server 2012. Can community help understand what might be going wrong here.
 **The same code runs absolutely fine locally on my windows machine**

Following is the output from my log file.
`=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Aug-2017::15:06:48 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.617.0> ([::1]:53485 -> [::1]:5672):
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to this was to create a durable queue and set heartbeat_interval to 0.